# SQL count as column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Table_One & Table_two. I have written an SQL statement that Joins Table_One to the latest record of Table_two. What I want is to include the read_reciept(count) as a column in the result.

Table_One:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Tom |
| 3 | Anna |

Table_two:

| ID | Visit ID | Date | read_reciept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2513 | 5/5/2001 | 1 |
| 1 | 84654 | 10/5/2012 | 1 |
| 1 | 454 | 4/20/2018 | 1 |
| 2 | 754 | 4/5/1999 | 0 |
| 2 | 654 | 8/8/2010 | 1 |
| 2 | 624 | 4/9/1982 | 1 |
| 3 | 7546 | 7/3/1997 | 0 |
| 3 | 246574 | 6/4/2015 | 1 |
| 3 | 15487 | 3/4/2017 | 1 |

This is the code I adopted:

```
SELECT ID, Name, VisitID, Date
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.VisitID, t2.Date,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) rn
    FROM Table_One t1
    INNER JOIN Table_Two t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
) t 
WHERE rn = 1
```

The result of the code:

| ID | Name | Visit ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 454 | 4/20/2018 |
| 2 | Tom | 654 | 8/8/2010 |
| 3 | Anna | 246574 | 6/4/2015 |

**Results needed:**

| ID | Name | Visit ID | Date | read_reciept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 454 | 4/20/2018 | 3 |
| 2 | Tom | 654 | 8/8/2010 | 2 |
| 3 | Anna | 246574 | 6/4/2015 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `count()` with `case when` clause :

```
SELECT ID, Name, VisitID, Date, read_reciept
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.VisitID, t2.Date,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) rn,
        count(case when read_receipt = 1 then 1 end) over (PARTITION BY t2.ID) AS read_reciept
    FROM Table_One t1
    INNER JOIN Table_Two t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
) t 
WHERE rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/S8OrPzsj)

Comment: I adapted the code to my database and the count is wrong. https://dbfiddle.uk/uw028l06

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, Name, VisitID, Date, sum_read_receipt
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.VisitID, t2.Date,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) rn,
        sum(read_receipt) over (PARTITION BY t2.ID) AS sum_read_receipt
    FROM Table_One t1
    INNER JOIN Table_Two t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Result given your data:

```
+----+------+---------+------------+------------------+
| ID | Name | VisitID | Date       | sum_read_receipt |
+----+------+---------+------------+------------------+
|  1 | John |     454 | 2018-04-20 |                3 |
|  2 | Tom  |     654 | 2010-08-08 |                2 |
|  3 | Anna |   15487 | 2017-03-04 |                2 |
+----+------+---------+------------+------------------+
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/j1MOxy-V)

Tip: Use YYYY-MM-DD for [MySQL date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: I adapted the code to my database and the count was wrong, https://dbfiddle.uk/5sJQ56NC

Comment: Well, this demonstrates the technique. I'll leave it to you to adapt to your database. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @BillKarwin's answer, I tried the equivalent of MSSQL's `OUTER APPLY` in MySQL:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2a.VisitID, t2a.Date, t2b.sum_read_receipt
FROM Table_One t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, SUM(read_receipt) AS sum_read_receipt 
    FROM Table_Two GROUP BY ID
) t2b ON t2b.ID = t1.ID
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT VisitID, Date FROM Table_Two t2a 
    WHERE t2a.ID = t1.ID ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
) t2a ON 1=1
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/axFl2vxN)